# Alert a message when mouse cursor latitude is equal to markers latitude (Google Maps API v3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have recently started working on google maps API V3 and right now I am stucked in a problem.

I have two markers plotted on my map. What I want is that on moving the mouse cursor on map, it continuously checks for latitude and when the latitude is equal to that of the marker present on map it should show an alert message.

**The problem which I am facing is that it is working only for one marker, not for all markers present on map**

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $('meta[name="_home_url"]').attr('content') + '/walkalong/' + position.coords.latitude + "/" + position.coords.longitude,
        success: function (response) {

            // Looping through all the entries from the JSON data
            for (var i = 0; i < response.data.shops.length; i++) {
                // Current object
                var obj = response.data.shops[i];

               // Sets the map marker
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(obj.latitude, obj.longitude),
                    map: map,
                    info: contentString,
                    optimized: false,
                    icon: pinIcon,
                    id: obj.shop_id,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    title: obj.title // this works, giving the marker a title with the correct title
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function (event) {
                    Latfetch = event.latLng.lat().toFixed(4);
                    Longfetch = event.latLng.lng().toFixed(4);
                    if (Latfetch === obj.latitude) {
                        alert(obj.latitude);
                    }

                });
```

and the JSON response is:

```
{"status":200,"data":{"shops":[{"shop_id":7,"name":"reebok","logo":"543813f8-cc75-4217-a3d4-bb08992f66af.png","latitude":"17.4539","longitude":"78.3902","shop_description":"","opening_time":"09:00:00","closing_time":"18:00:00","mobile":"4567896545","address_line1":"ameerpet","city":"Dispur","state":"Arunachal Pradesh","country":"India","pincode":"435645","baazar_area":"","front_image":"6c08a359-fb7f-4e09-af25-3c2d43a32327.jpg","distance":0.703},{"shop_id":9,"name":"ahex","logo":"86c6f7f8-625c-4a7a-aee4-10f7d16f1f12.jpg","latitude":"17.4519","longitude":"78.3879","shop_description":"","opening_time":"09:00:00","closing_time":"18:00:00","mobile":"4233488384","address_line1":"madhapur","city":"Panaji","state":"Goa","country":"India","pincode":"345678","baazar_area":"","front_image":"31e96273-c360-4b49-87d1-418bdac26dc3.jpg","distance":0.711}],"shopImages":[{"logo":"543813f8-cc75-4217-a3d4-bb08992f66af.png","front_image":"6c08a359-fb7f-4e09-af25-3c2d43a32327.jpg","internal_image":"e988011f-f2c1-4b08-8582-0f36e85dc4f9.jpg","rack_image":"rack.jpeg","product_image":"item.jpeg"}]}}
```

Anyone there who could help?

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess it just works only for one because you can only add one listener for `mousemove`. You could add the event on the marker instead:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < response.data.shops.length; i++) {
    ...
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        ...
    });

    marker.addListener('mousemove', function(event) {
         var latfetch = event.latLng.lat().toFixed(4);
         var longfetch = event.latLng.lng().toFixed(4);
         var lat = this.position.lat();
         if(latfetch === lat){
              alert(lat);
         }
    });
}
```